# how to create a new column in a dataframe based on conditions in another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
df1:

Variables     left      right
0  AUM           -0.001    28.20
1  AUM           28.20     40.28
2  AUM           40.28     58.27
3  AUM           58.27     80.72
4  AUM           80.72     100.00
0  ABS           -88.01    200.72
1  ABS           200.72    480.72
2  ABS           480.72    800.20
0  LS            10000     200000
1  LS            200000    400000
```

```
df2:
   
    Pan_no     ABS      AUM     LS      
0   AAA        28        30    10001      
2   CCC        500       98    390000     
1   BBB        250       50    150000     
3   DDD        100       60    380000     
4   EEE         88       10    378347
```

Conditions:

Based on the left and right value in df1, a new column should be created in df2 and the values inside
the column should be the index of df1 for that particular variable.

Example:
In df2 if AUM value falls under this range (-0.001 - 28.20) then the new column will have the index value
of df1 as the new value. i.e 0

Similarly,

In df2 if ABS value falls under this range (200.72 - 480.72) then the new column ABS_BIN will have the index value of df1 as the new value. i.e 1

WHat i have tried is:

```
binning_vars = ['ABS','AUM','LS']
def f(row):
  for i in binning_vars:
      for j in df1[df1['Variable'] == i].index:
            if df1[i] >= df1['left'] & df1[i] >= df1['right']:
                value = j
            else:
                pass
            return value
df2[i,'_bin'] = df1.apply(f, axis=1)
```

but it throws an error as TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Expected Output:
with new columns in df2:
    
    Pan_no     ABS      AUM     LS      ABS_BIN    AUM_BIN     LS_BIN
0   AAA        28        30    10001      0          1           0
1   BBB        250       50    150000     1          2           0
2   CCC        500       98    390000     2          4           1
3   DDD        100       60    380000     0          3           1
4   EEE         88       10    378347     0          0           1
```

Comment: Well documented question and code. +1

Comment: For the discussion below, what is the size of your dataset: how many rows, how many variables?

Comment: 5 lakh rows and 10 variables

Comment: Can you provide your actual dataset or your data is confidential?

Comment: it's confidential :)

Comment: Then we will not be able to evaluate the best solution :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and avoid loops inside the `binning` function:

```
def binning(sr):
    df = df1.loc[df1['Variables'] == sr.name, ['left', 'right']]
    bins = sorted(set(df.to_numpy().ravel()))
    return pd.cut(sr, bins=bins, labels=df.index)

out = df2[binning_vars].apply(binning).add_suffix('_BIN')
df2 = pd.concat([df2, out], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
  Pan_no  ABS  AUM      LS ABS_BIN AUM_BIN LS_BIN
0    AAA   28   30   10001       0       1      0
2    CCC  500   98  390000       2       4      1
1    BBB  250   50  150000       1       2      0
3    DDD  100   60  380000       0       3      1
4    EEE   88   10  378347       0       0      1
```

Comment: @sammywemmy. Thanks. Now, I specified inside the function. Loops on a few columns are not impactful compared to loops on rows

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge_asof` to avoid using `apply`:

```
out = df2.merge(
 pd.merge_asof((df2.melt(id_vars='Pan_no')
                   .astype({'value': float})
                   .sort_values(by='value')
                ),
               df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='left'),
               left_by='variable', right_by='Variables',
               left_on='value', right_on='left', direction='backward')
  .pivot(index='Pan_no', columns='variable', values='index')
  .add_suffix('_BIN'),
    left_on='Pan_no', right_index=True
)
```

output:

```
  Pan_no  ABS  AUM      LS  ABS_BIN  AUM_BIN  LS_BIN
0    AAA   28   30   10001        0        1       0
2    CCC  500   98  390000        2        4       1
1    BBB  250   50  150000        1        2       0
3    DDD  100   60  380000        0        3       1
4    EEE   88   10  378347        0        0       1
```

Comment: speed tests!! :) apply might be faster here because of the sorting (which could be expensive), and the transformation to long form... the binning maintains the same number of rows ... I've been proven wrong before though

Comment: @sammywemmy I was about to test it, I also don't expect a huge difference as this requires melt/pivot/merge as well. I mostly did it for the fun :p

Comment: @sammy, it's about the same speed, `apply` is slightly faster (3.9 vs 4.1 ms), but I'm not sure how to test on a larger dataset due to the duplicates

Comment: that's the deal breaker --- duplicates, even for binning duplicates i'm not sure will hold. fortunately, this question does not have that issue, or overlapping intervals

Comment: Exactly, overlapping intervals would be a pain to handle with `merge_asof` :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I use also `pd.cut` here because there is no overlapping. It's easy to implement a MP version of `binning` function

Comment: since you are merging, you might as well just use merge, filter after and pivot... that should take care of overlaps  ... hopefully

Comment: @sammywemmy yes, but the drawback is that it can explode the size if there are duplicates/overlaps

Comment: @Corralien it **looks** more fancy :p More seriously, I'd be interested in having feedback on a real dataset. It's hard to test with only the provided sample.

Comment: I used `df2 = df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(1000000)).reset_index(drop=True)` but the problem is your solution failed with duplicate entries. I don't know why.

Comment: The Zen of Python: Simple is better than complex. ;-) I don't see anything about fancy :p

Comment: @Corralien don't be mad, I am not picking the answer, I already UV yours :p

Comment: Oh, don't think that of me. I'm not angry. I'm just a little surprised is all. I know that your answers are generally more relevant than mine.

Comment: @Corralien don't worry, I know (thus the `:p`)